# how not to use length (l=) in DKIM-signature in phpmailer

Tags: settings, phpmailer, dkim

Is there a way to use an extra parameter to avoid the length (l=) tag in the DKIM-signature ?

Also I am looking for a way to change the alignment mode from "relaxed/simple" into "relaxed/relaxed", but I cannot find a way.

As I understood, it is recommended NOT to use l= (especially if you have troubles reaching hotmail-addresses) and use "relaxed/relaxed"

I am using phpmailer 5.2.7

Looking forward to your answer

Comment: No there isn't - though you can simply subclass and override that part of the DKIM header generation if you want it to act differently. Why are you using 5.2.7? It's ancient, buggy and vulnerable. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hello Synchro, thanks for your answer.

I was able to change the phpmailer.class hardcoded:

$DKIMcanonicalization = 'relaxed/relaxed'; (this does the job)

and simply did:

//            $DKIMquery . "; l=" .

But now I get:

dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify) 

so, no "pass"

Comment: You can't just change what it *says* the canonicalisation is, you have to actually make it work that way. [Read the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6376#section-3.4) for the difference. Pull requests welcome!

Comment: I've read the RFC but this is quite complicated. Isn't there a subclass available that does  already "relaxed/relaxed" ? I've looked at the latest version of phpmailer but here the standard also seems "relaxed/simple"

Comment: No, but you're quite welcome to write one and submit a PR - that's how the existing DKIM support came to be.